# Find a folder excluding one

Tags: find, path

I would like to find a folder not named "STDF", then archive them.

```
find /a/b/c -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -path "STDF" -exec /usr/bin/gzip '{}' \;
```

The above command is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? are you are getting any error ?

Comment: yes, I get 


gzip: /a/b/c/BB2222 is a directory -- ignored

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
find /where/to/look/ -type d -not -name STDF
```

to find the folder

now that you mentioned the error you get I see you are using gzip for compressing a folder, and you can't do that. look at [this answer](http://www.mkyong.com/linux/linux-how-to-gzip-a-folder/) for more information about how to compress a folder

Comment: gzip: /a/b/c/BB1111 is a directory -- ignored

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: You don't want gzip, you want tar

Answer (score 1):

The `gzip` command requires the `r` flag.

```
find /a/b/c -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '*STDF*' -exec sh -c 'tar -zcvf "${1}".tar.gz "$@"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error.
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]

Comment: @user548682 I updated the answer which uses `tar` with `gzip` compression.

Comment: thanks. Im able to get the result i want. 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/a/b/c/BB2222/
Is this considered normal? What it means?

Comment: Also, can u explain the following command?
sh -c 'tar -zcvf "${1}".tar.gz "$@"' _ {}

Comment: I have one more question. When I tried to extract the .tar.gz file, it will store the file in another folder, with same path, meaning /a/b/c/a/b/c/BB2222. Why? I want it to be placed under /a/b/c; or current dir, as I will move it to another dir.

Comment: @user548682  Have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: I think this would work too: `find /a/b/c -mindepth 1 -type d ! -name '*STDF*' -prune -exec tar -zcvf {}.tar.gz {} \;`. Now, stripping the leading /a/b/c/ from all the paths of all the files in the tarballs might be a little trickier